# Alterar dado da Coluna usando Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

estou tentando aprender panda mas estou com uma dúvida aqui

Eu tenho os seguintes dados:

```
PSG    CLASS   
AAA     1  
BBB     2 
CCC     3 
DDD     1
```

Eu queria criar uma nova coluna, utilizando Pandas, com o nome de Classe e com as informações de "Primeira", "Segunda" e "Terceira" de acordo com os número 1, 2, 3 respectivamente.

Basicamente eu queria criar algo como "Se CLASS = 1 então a coluna CLASSE recebe PRIMEIRA"

Mas eu não consegui encontrar como fazer, agradeceria muito a ajuda de vocês!

Obrigado,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo do exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'PSG':['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'], 'CLASS':[1,2,3,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

>>> print df
   CLASS  PSG
0      1  AAA
1      2  BBB
2      3  CCC
3      1  DDD
```

Criamos uma regra para definir as classes

```
def define_classe(num):
    if num == 1:
        return 'PRIMEIRO'
    elif num == 2:
        return 'SEGUNDO'
    elif num == 3:
        return 'TERCEIRO'
    return 'SEM_CLASSE'
```

E ai aplicamos a regra

```
df['CLASSE'] = df['CLASS'].map(define_classe)

>>> print df
   CLASS  PSG    CLASSE
0      1  AAA  PRIMEIRO
1      2  BBB   SEGUNDO
2      3  CCC  TERCEIRO
3      1  DDD  PRIMEIRO
```

Comment: Meu, me ajudou demais! Muito obrigado!