# Python - Selecionar 2 colunas de um DF e classificá-las

Tags: python-3.x

Sou novo no mundo da programação, e estou fazendo uns estudos com o objetivo de ganhar conhecimentos na área de Data Science.

Vamos lá... eu tenho um Dataframe com uma série de informações, dentre ela gênero e idade.
Eu quero trazer a quantidade de linhas de cada gênero (masculino e feminino) e classificá-las como crianças (0 a > 12 anos), jovens (12 a > 18 anos) e adultos (18+ anos).

Eu estou perdido ao ponto de não saber nem se comecei certo...

```
Input: df.groupby("Sex").Age.unique()
Output: 
Sex
female    [38.0, 26.0, 35.0, 27.0, 14.0, 4.0, 58.0, 55.0...
male      [22.0, 35.0, 29.0, 54.0, 2.0, 20.0, 39.0, 34.0...
Name: Age, dtype: object

Variável:
classification = df.groupby("Sex").Age.unique()
```

Agora imagino que eu tenha que fazer um for loop, é isso? Mas como nomear cada caso.

Comment: Para saber a quantidade basta fazer `len(classification[i])`, com i igual a 0 para female e 1 para male. Para classificar, veja se esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321304/alterar-dado-da-coluna-usando-pandas/321317#321317) te ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo desse DataFrame:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd

d = {'Sex':['female','female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male','male','male'],
     'Age':[38.0,26.0,4.0,14.0,33.0,24.0,7.0,16.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

>>> print(df)
    Age     Sex
0  38.0  female
1  26.0  female
2   4.0  female
3  14.0  female
4  33.0    male
5  24.0    male
6   7.0    male
7  16.0    male
```

Fazemos a classificação pela idade:

```
def define_classe(idade):
    if idade >= 18:
        return 'Adulto'
    elif idade >= 12:
        return 'Jovem'
    return 'Criança'

df['Classification'] = df['Age'].map(define_classe)
>>> print(df)
    Age     Sex Classification
0  38.0  female         Adulto
1  26.0  female         Adulto
2   4.0  female        Criança
3  14.0  female          Jovem
4  33.0    male         Adulto
5  24.0    male         Adulto
6   7.0    male        Criança
7  16.0    male          Jovem
```

E agora é só filtrar os campos. No exemplo, Adulto Homem:

```
>>> print (len(df.loc[df['Classification'] == 'Adulto'].loc[df['Sex'] == 'male']))
2
```

Um outro jeito seria filtrar direto os valores, sem fazer a classificação antes:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Age'] >= 18].loc[df['Sex'] == 'male']
    Age   Sex Classification
4  33.0  male         Adulto
5  24.0  male         Adulto

>>> print(len(df.loc[df['Age'] >= 18].loc[df['Sex'] == 'male']))
2

>>> print(df.loc[df['Age'] >= 12].loc[df['Age'] < 18].loc[df['Sex'] == 'male'])
    Age   Sex Classification
7  16.0  male          Jovem

>>> print(len(df.loc[df['Age'] >= 12].loc[df['Age'] < 18].loc[df['Sex'] == 'male']))
1
```

Comment: Deu certo Alex. Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se você apenas quer trocar os valores dessa colunas por crianças, jovens e adultos você pode utilizar o método .apply em cada coluna:

primeiro você cria uma função:

```
def classifica_idade(x):
    if < 12:
        returne criança
    elif x >= 12 and x <= 18:
        returne joven
    returne adulto
```

isso feito basta ir no dataframe e aplicar na coluna que deseja da seguinte forma:
classification['coluna_desejada'] = classification['coluna_desejada'].apply(classifica_idade())

funciona também con funções lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez eu não tenha sido  claro... meu objetivo é ter um resultado parecido com esse:

Children Female: x amount

Young Female: y amount

Adult Female: z amount

Children Male: n amount

Young Male: k amount

Adult Male: j amount

Eu evoluí criando um novo dataframe com apenas as colunas Sex e Age. Creio que vai ser mais fácil continuar daqui...

Comment: Por favor não faça comentários no campo de resposta. Você pode editar sua pergunta.

Comment: Ok, não sabia. E muito obrigado pelo apoio!