# DataFrame - Pandas. Atribuindo valores em colunas a partir da comparação de outra coluna

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho o seguinte DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp': [1,2,3,4,1], 
               'name_emp': ['x','y','z','w','x'], 
               'donnated_value':[1100,11000,500,300,1000],
               'refound_value':[22000,22000,50000,450,90]
            })
df['return_percentagem'] = 100 * df['refound_value']/df['donnated_value']
df['classification_roi'] = ''
```

Quero atribuir valores para df['classification_roi'] a partir dos valores de df['return_percentagem']. Exemplo: Valores de df["return_percentagem'] > 100, df['classification_roi'] = 'Bom investimento';Valores de df["return_percentagem'] entre 99 e 50, df['classification_roi'] = 'Médio investimento';Valores de df["return_percentagem'] <50 , df['classification_roi'] = 'Péssimo investimento'.

Estou tentando o seguinte, porém todas as linhas recebem como valor 'Bad Investment', ou seja, todos estão entrando no primeiro loop

```
def comunidade():
for i in df['return_percentagem'].values:
    if i < 50:        
        df['classification_roi'] = 'Bad Investment'
    elif i >=50 and i < 100:
        df['classification_roi'] = 'Median Investment'
    elif i >= 100:
        df['classification_roi'] = 'Good Investment'
comunidade()
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pandas, quando fazemos: `df['coluna'] = 'valor'`, **todos os campos de `'coluna'` são preenchidos com `'valor'`**. Tanto que, ao fazer `df['classification_roi'] = ''`, todos as linhas da coluna `classification_roi` recebem o valor `''`.

No seu código, dentro da função `comunidade()`, você está fazendo `df['classification_roi'] = string`. No ultimo `i` do `for i in df['return_percentagem'].values:`, o `i` recebe `9.0`, então a condição `if i < 50:` é verdadeira e o comando `df['classification_roi'] = 'Bad Investment'` é executado, **fazendo com que todas as linhas da coluna `classification_roi` fiquem com o valor `'Bad Investment'`**. Mas veja que, ao longo do `for`, a coluna `classification_roi` é alterada diversas vezes. Por isso a sua conclusão "ou seja, todos estão entrando no primeiro loop" está errada.

Para alterar corretamente o valor de cada linha da coluna `classification_roi`, uma solução é seguir [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373395/dataframe-pandas-criando-nova-coluna-ap%C3%B3s-compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-colunas?answertab=active#tab-top):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['return_percentagem'] < 50:
        df.loc[index,'classification_roi'] = 'Bad Investment'
    elif row['return_percentagem'] < 100:
        df.loc[index,'classification_roi'] = 'Median Investment'
    elif row['return_percentagem'] >= 100:
        df.loc[index,'classification_roi'] = 'Good Investment'
```

Ou [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321304/alterar-dado-da-coluna-usando-pandas/321317#321317):

```
def comunidade(num):
    if num < 50:        
        return 'Bad Investment'
    elif num < 100:
        return 'Median Investment'
    elif num >= 100:
        return 'Good Investment'

df['classification_roi'] = df['return_percentagem'].map(comunidade)
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso usando a função `select` do **numpy**, passando um array de condições, um de resultados e um valor para `default`

```
condicao = [df['return_percentagem'] < 50,
            df['return_percentagem'] < 100]

resultados = ['Bad Investment', 'Median Investment']

df['classification_roi'] = np.select(condicao, resultados, 'Good Investment')

output:

    id_emp  name_emp    donnated_value  refound_value   return_percentagem  classification_roi
0   1       x           1100            22000           2000.0              Good Investment
1   2       y           11000           22000           200.0               Good Investment
2   3       z           500             50000           10000.0             Good Investment
3   4       w           300             450             150.0               Good Investment
4   1       x           1000            90              9.0                 Bad Investment
```